# How to extend type and change its methods' return types

Tags: typescript

I have an Advanced type, I want to exclude some methods from it and also change the return type of some methods in it.

What I have currently done is create a different type and copied all methods from type 1 to type 2, for which I want to somehow skip this.

Is there any possible way to do this by simple using `Omit` for the methods I want to exclude, and somehow also able to change the return type of others.

Here is what I am currently have:

```ts
type IColumnSelector<T> = (x: T) => any;
type ArrayIColumnSelector<T> = (x: T) => any[];
declare type SingleValue =
    | string
    | number
    | boolean
    | Date
    | undefined
    | null;
declare type ArrayValue = any[] | undefined;
declare type NumberValue = number | undefined;
declare type StringValue = string | undefined;
type R<T, S extends string> = Record<S, T>;

type IWhere<T, ParentType, D extends string> = {
    /**
     * Select based on Column
     */
    Column: (column: IColumnSelector<T>) => IWhere<T, ParentType, D>;
    /**
     * EqualTo based on value or column from a table
     */
    EqualTo: (value: SingleValue | IColumnSelector<T>) => IWhere<T, ParentType, D>;
    /**
     * Contains based on value or column from a table
     */
    Contains: (value: StringValue | IColumnSelector<T>) => IWhere<T, ParentType, D>;
    /**
     * StartsWith based on value or column from a table
     */
    StartsWith: (value: StringValue | IColumnSelector<T>) => IWhere<T, ParentType, D>;
    /**
     * EndsWith based on value or column from a table
     */
    EndsWith: (value: StringValue | IColumnSelector<T>) => IWhere<T, ParentType, D>;
    /**
     * NotEqualTo based on value or column from a table
     */
    NotEqualTo: (value: SingleValue | IColumnSelector<T>) => IWhere<T, ParentType, D>;
    /**
     * EqualAndGreaterThen based on value or column from a table
     */
    EqualAndGreaterThen: (value: NumberValue | StringValue | IColumnSelector<T>) => IWhere<T, ParentType, D>;
    /**
     * EqualAndLessThen based on value or column from a table
     */
    EqualAndLessThen: (value: NumberValue | StringValue | IColumnSelector<T>) => IWhere<T, ParentType, D>;
    /**
     * Add (
     */
    Start: IWhere<T, ParentType, D>;
    /**
     * Add )
     */
    End: IWhere<T, ParentType, D>;
    /**
     * Add OR
     */
    OR: IWhere<T, ParentType, D>;
    /**
     * Add AND
     */
    AND: IWhere<T, ParentType, D>;
    /**
     * GreaterThan based on value or column from a table
     */
    GreaterThan: (value: NumberValue | StringValue | IColumnSelector<T>) => IWhere<T, ParentType, D>;
    /**
     * LessThan based on value or column from a table
     */
    LessThan: (value: NumberValue | StringValue | IColumnSelector<T>) => IWhere<T, ParentType, D>;
    /**
     * IN based on array Value or column from a table
     */
    IN: (value: ArrayValue | IColumnSelector<T>) => IWhere<T, ParentType, D>;
    /**
     * Add NOT
     */
    Not: IWhere<T, ParentType, D>;
    /**
     * Add IS NULL
     */
    Null: IWhere<T, ParentType, D>;
    /**
     * Add IS NOT NULL
     */
    NotNull: IWhere<T, ParentType, D>;
    /**
     * OrderByDesc COLUMN OR COLUMNS
     */
    OrderByDesc: (columnName: IColumnSelector<T> | ArrayIColumnSelector<T>) => IWhere<T, ParentType, D>;
    /**
     * OrderByAsc COLUMN OR COLUMNS
     */
    OrderByAsc: (columnName: IColumnSelector<T> | ArrayIColumnSelector<T>) => IWhere<T, ParentType, D>;
    /**
     * Limit the rows
     */
    Limit: (value: number) => IWhere<T, ParentType, D>;
    /**
     * GroupBy column or columns
     */
    GroupBy: (columnName: IColumnSelector<T> | ArrayIColumnSelector<T>) => IWhere<T, ParentType, D>;
    /**
     * delete based on Query above.
     */
    delete: () => Promise<void>;
};

type JoinOn<T, ParentType, D extends string> = {
    /**
     * Inner join a table
     * eg InnerJoin<TableB, "b">("TableB", "b").Column(x=> x.a.id).EqualTo(x=> x.b.parentId)...
     */
    InnerJoin: <B, S extends string>(tableName: D, alias: S) => JoinOn<T & R<B, S>, ParentType, D>;
    /**
     * left join a table
     * eg LeftJoin<TableB, "b">("TableB", "b").Column(x=> x.a.id).EqualTo(x=> x.b.parentId)...
     */
    LeftJoin: <B, S extends string>(tableName: D, alias: S) => JoinOn<T & R<B, S>, ParentType, D>;
    /**
     * right join a table
     * eg RightJoin<TableB, "b">("TableB", "b").Column(x=> x.a.id).EqualTo(x=> x.b.parentId)...
     */
    RightJoin: <B, S extends string>(tableName: D, alias: S) => JoinOn<T & R<B, S>, ParentType, D>;
    Column: (column: IColumnSelector<T>) => JoinOn<T, ParentType, D>;
    EqualTo: (value: SingleValue | IColumnSelector<T>) => JoinOn<T, ParentType, D>;
    Contains: (value: StringValue | IColumnSelector<T>) => JoinOn<T, ParentType, D>;
    StartsWith: (value: StringValue | IColumnSelector<T>) => JoinOn<T, ParentType, D>;
    EndsWith: (value: StringValue | IColumnSelector<T>) => JoinOn<T, ParentType, D>;
    NotEqualTo: (value: SingleValue | IColumnSelector<T>) => JoinOn<T, ParentType, D>;
    EqualAndGreaterThen: (value: NumberValue | StringValue | IColumnSelector<T>) => JoinOn<T, ParentType, D>;
    EqualAndLessThen: (value: NumberValue | StringValue | IColumnSelector<T>) => JoinOn<T, ParentType, D>;
    Start: JoinOn<T, ParentType, D>;
    End: JoinOn<T, ParentType, D>;
    OR: JoinOn<T, ParentType, D>;
    AND: JoinOn<T, ParentType, D>;
    GreaterThan: (value: NumberValue | StringValue | IColumnSelector<T>) => JoinOn<T, ParentType, D>;
    LessThan: (value: NumberValue | StringValue | IColumnSelector<T>) => JoinOn<T, ParentType, D>;
    IN: (value: ArrayValue | IColumnSelector<T>) => JoinOn<T, ParentType, D>;
    Not: JoinOn<T, ParentType, D>;
    Null: JoinOn<T, ParentType, D>;
    NotNull: JoinOn<T, ParentType, D>;
    Where: IWhere<T, ParentType, D>;
};


type IHaving<T, ParentType, D extends string> = {
    Column: (columnOrAlias: IColumnSelector<T> | string) => IHaving<T, ParentType, D>;
    EqualTo: (value: SingleValue | IColumnSelector<T>) => IHaving<T, ParentType, D>;
    Contains: (value: StringValue | IColumnSelector<T>) => IHaving<T, ParentType, D>;
    StartsWith: (value: StringValue | IColumnSelector<T>) => IHaving<T, ParentType, D>;
    EndsWith: (value: StringValue | IColumnSelector<T>) => IHaving<T, ParentType, D>;
    NotEqualTo: (value: SingleValue | IColumnSelector<T>) => IHaving<T, ParentType, D>;
    EqualAndGreaterThen: (value: NumberValue | StringValue | IColumnSelector<T>) => IHaving<T, ParentType, D>;
    EqualAndLessThen: (value: NumberValue | StringValue | IColumnSelector<T>) => IHaving<T, ParentType, D>;
    Start: IHaving<T, ParentType, D>;
    End: IHaving<T, ParentType, D>;
    OR: IHaving<T, ParentType, D>;
    AND: IHaving<T, ParentType, D>;
    GreaterThan: (value: NumberValue | StringValue | IColumnSelector<T>) => IHaving<T, ParentType, D>;
    LessThan: (value: NumberValue | StringValue | IColumnSelector<T>) => IHaving<T, ParentType, D>;
    IN: (value: ArrayValue | IColumnSelector<T>) => IHaving<T, ParentType, D>;
    Not: IHaving<T, ParentType, D>;
    Null: IWhere<T, ParentType, D>;
    NotNull: IWhere<T, ParentType, D>;
    OrderByDesc: (columnName: IColumnSelector<T> | ArrayIColumnSelector<T>) => IHaving<T, ParentType, D>;
    OrderByAsc: (columnName: IColumnSelector<T> | ArrayIColumnSelector<T>) => IHaving<T, ParentType, D>;
    Limit: (value: number) => IWhere<T, ParentType, D>;
    GroupBy: (columnName: IColumnSelector<T> | ArrayIColumnSelector<T>) => IHaving<T, ParentType, D>;
    delete: () => Promise<void>;
}
```

What I want is have `IHaving` and `JoinOn` inherit `IWhere` but also make some differences, so that it look like the current `IHaving` and `JoinOn` with minimum code.

Is there a way to simplify this?

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgwgewDYFcC2A7AyhJEDGwCATgDwAqAfFALxQAUAHgFxTkCUt1AhhiANwAoUJCgBBYsW4h4ydNlwEiZKrQYs2nGjz4BtALpCAJgSTdi0EdCwBLDAHM8ANW6poNQVC9QAPlADOwMR29p7efhjoAEYQxGFeflEIyBC88b5QACLcwBDpfigYJgBmdhBG+VCRSEjGpuaW4NASUiAubmq8IAYZhSVlRnX4ZhZQVlAActGx7SjuVdPEvUUQpRjlQyONolhBIbPzgcEOy-3rg8JNUABKFAA0UFhQEIy5Rf4Bew7UdNcEJEZSFgHlQhJdRDAAOoAC1iEHuUAACg0MMByE0Hplnq8IO9Psd7D8oABvdIAegAVBT0lAKY9FIQoFFuP5ylAEBgoIhUJgaRSyelufJWPR8HJMKxZDyFHhCCQKJQtNQobCLAjkRZUejIJjKEJvFBKdSDbSoABRACOKFc5AQTJZbI5UAAbq45uylmLpVBisQEGgoNwxtwong+QKDZbrUhbSLXW5WLYHM43dA-FL5DhZcoFUrYDC4eqUWiMVk9eSqXyuRzgNw7B9mayjOzOfH3SQoF75D6-QGg7XQ3kTfzBTW6xh-HHU4mvvYDhkM5gs0p5VQ8yrC+QHhrcSWdWX9d4jVXduZgP5ITZgND7U2Wy7Ux7O+LOb7-YHg4Pw+lT8Rz5frynBNHlned0yFJcGRzNcuHzVV4S3JFi21CBdUPLxj2Hc13gAm9G0dVtHw7LtMB7d9+xDMNhwjbwzRwq9oSAuYZwJMDYAgmUVxURVYI3NVEJ3LVS0ycsDUwg06QmBBgCjG07Xw5snTbaBiJfMi+0-KiJJorwpJkq05KYiBExCFMOnAl9lzlbj1wLfjt2Q4TRKPSssNkpAxCKABxCwclichYU5BT72Up8SNfXsPwHLTvBHSMDI87zfNyYgAtxIzWCmNAYmINjdlYx8LOlKzoJ47Q4M3BzNT3VCDwrY0JPNBLPKMAAZCB-H8NKgodRTCI6VTvTfDToqHbT0nclr2s67qMsmRY8tAwr2MsqDVzK5U7IQqrdxQtD6qrMQjGbehvwNX9gElLai2qva6rE1zGqO5t2DO2iiiu+Cbt2pz0MNR7YvEY6oAAeWuN6vDBz7KqQ27foOrDnvECZMgh5HMmh+zYZ+-cRL+8TAZ81IUoC3hbwIh8Bs9NThqiyixtinSoCJvzUuhXg5qynLFoK8yVuKtabN466BMc3HnIwgGvDpaauvZnq7yUojqaGyKKK-aj0ll0mME5hblvy-ZlsXTjrNzYWvtFuHxfxqXTRgCZyb6wNJGkKB50G7tafVmLpaZh25paaQ2JNkr1tsy2dqEm2Eae4GJhB8g0b0zHtux6Parx2PAaRmAngmABVVrWuTlAalT76M-2h6Gpz4G88mRPJiLkvNYNPSpnLiqscEmrq5c2vpdB4gTGIAAhEBMg6-AuRB1qC4AWUdsHZ-npesDRkGR9iCep-8fARXCiZuDQYz+czQWFQyIOZA4sOhfKvi097u6s5rqst9HiexH31fF+X64f916b23uPEAP8D4MCPifM+odL6qD8DfOB2Zw4Wxhi-eG78sKtRsGgK8YxYRQD9AAd38GjHBeDLoMGUqwSI2VYgR3QWLTOEt-qD1ND5BAKAwAT2fN6T2mAyFt28Jw7hE9D4vmPqfSUd94HUEQa7W+q0UEP02pHdOfd7oDyrCYPAuQnb3gAIpzGICAQMSRnQQAAHRo10RAXIIo8yIl7DYVkpBnQIBsEYcsABfME4wABSniMAgwwJXTRWIXhvCMB8I4IQiSkiwY1GAGB1hLAAFbBLphrRqEB7CwFSbEIJdgKD0zHg8AARFECplB6AVPIGUiplTqnsCsRxJg5VGBWO4FYrxrT3K2g6dQLpUQrFgGLDAIwrSrE2OEV4FJaTim6ygKQcpjxsTRNibOWpo0pFn0yA8VwNgWSJjzEs0JFAoAADIbirIeFgSgUcImsIJkPPAxRgBQEyXYbJvtTR5KgO1D5SzSmDjWVUmpdSGlgqaVACFrT2mME6d03pUyrEDIQEMqAIyxkTLRTM8hqxgBLNYHc9ZUTcQxPxPE+guyYGsAOYGJAxzJyPDOcEi55Brm3LWQ8p5r8Xl2zpMEew0JPnfM5D7BmQ8AXXBsKK4lwTQV4HBdU2p9TGnNIqQil8WKuk9L6eihKgykXDKsaM8Z1VJnTNmeNA0cqFUkpWbyjZlKtkEh2fTPZDLDnMpOWy2C5ywlcpubcXljyNECr+hxCR0oZHKK4ubcqQbwlRomsahAc0kyOAgCHWRKik3UBTVbHGLDo1jnrFmpafNkGJpgsmjlwb+WYO8BdC8DEq283dEVC+Bb61FsbamltXg6IxNwp2o2Nb811o2lAYtzaY7t2khirNplc3G2nWbftc7B0lqrlokdzUkrE38oFPW9DcoG2rd28+kE+2zvnZG4dTVoxTQ6nLdK1DpzzQvTzSdN7a1bofbuhdZafy1j-KwR9GDF3vSMFBkDT7YOQ2uAhuwnLQP9y8GIFGaGQlNqQ2Bg0LMSby3PdzK9Xa0y3tNqVdl6GCMwaI94bWZGv3AS5jMSj-7qOAbo4GxDTGsOwAmIHRReaE1Afo-hodyHJjSTwxhwjwnO5IEU4x5hKnpKqfU7J5jXgtoVz3c8oQfjBDmfGDAAAEtwZ0IQ9OYldXiOJ3w1CJO8DGqBL4t5iD9ayvj60MgufsOuGzdmHAOYPS+wy7HmKPDXRJgW97Qu2fs8ZtNBpEConHKy+gNCQJUYXJu-jj8wtpcw1Ftt47Ytn0Ng4RLvaZ0pfC-YSLb84PtsAjVliPGiuSZK8qMrEX0vPr0iu7r8Xkzrqnf11BpXUvDYq+1w9r7j2s1mhNzjl6+Z1bnBu2bqjYBDdayNuTk0iisc-Xl79W2-31f20lprvFjttdYRdSUL3Tv6ewvBo7C2TtLdYVDP7LXXt-RwxjEH5XlNRZI6ejmm39Y7evbx4rc3Bv-bB1rd9OtyNceR4Vntd6nvzdB194TAcJs3wa8TqTz3Mfk6iynKHi2YfLfml3J+WOl3AB093Z+mmoufx3pPaesb5Depo-fK+CjWgBcO9ZhngO-rC7ARA8XmBJfy5l+IRR2vt2K7J8rrWuCrxzToTlRhPdBfs9ETwkAGuMBa7R9xa+euXeFpZwDtnrC7EOIYE4lxbiPFeN8YIIAA)

Comment: That's a lot of lines of types... Can you reduce that to just the part that matters for your example?

Comment: Indeed, a [mre] should probably fit entirely on a normal-sized screen with a normal-sized font, or else it's likely to be too long for Stack Overflow (that is, if you *can't* get the issue across in less than a screenful of text, it's probably too idiosyncratic to be useful to future readers)

Comment: Looks like you need interfaces: https://tsplay.dev/mbEOEN

Comment: @vr using interface togather with `Omit` and `extends` solved the issue thx. Add an answer and I should accept it

Answer (score 1):

Using interfaces lets us extend types in a safer manner, so if we have a base type `IQuery` which has all the shared members,

```
interface IQuery<T, ParentType, D extends string, R extends IQuery<T, ParentType, D, R>> {
    /**
     * Select based on Column
     */
    Column: (column: IColumnSelector<T>) => R;

    // ...
}
```

we can define the other kinds of queries by extending this one:

```
interface IWhere<T, ParentType, D extends string> extends IQuery<T, ParentType, D, IWhere<T, ParentType, D>> {
```

You may notice that we are passing `IWhere` to `IQuery`, and this is because `IQuery` needs the child type to know what to return (for example, in `Column`, it returns the child).

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgwgewDYFcC2A7AyhJEDGwCATgDwAqAfFALxQAUAHgFxTkCUt1AhhiANwAoUJCgBBYsW4h4ydNlwEiZKrQYs2nGjz4BtALpCAJgSTdi0EdCwBLDAHM8ANW6poNQVC9QAPlADOwMR29p7efhjoAEYQxGFeflEIyBC88b5QACLcwBDpfigYJgBmdhBG+VCRSEjGpuaW4NASUiAubmq8IAYZhSVlRnX4ZhZQVlAActGx7SjuVdPEvUUQpRjlQyONolhBIbPzgcEOy-3rg8JNUABKFAA0UFhQEIy5Rf4Bew7UdNcEJEZSFgHlQhII7LliMVuPhoDAAIpzYgge5QAAKDQwwHITQemWerwg70+x3sD2uBLeRg+CKRKPIDwxFixOMgePJlGoAG90gB6ABU-PSUH5j0UhCgUW4-nKUAQGCgiFQmGF-N56SV8lY9HwckwrFkyoUeEIJAolC01GuQm8UAFQttIqgAFEAI4oVzkBCS6Wy+VQABurjmcqWuqNUGKxAQaCg3DG3CieFV6ttbo9SC92qDblYtgczmD0D8hvkOBNynNlpuNu89tVivlwG4dg+UplRjlCpzIZIUHD8kj0dj8ebSbyjrVGqbLYw-mzRbzX3sBwypcw5aUZqo1etfMFDd25mA-gA6jZgAALH0druBouh-t6hVRmNxhPjlPpI-EE-nq8LrmjzLquJaahu4qVjuXA1vuDq2qKzrvP+17tn63YPn2A6YEOb6jomyaTqm3hIdSKGAXMS6kqBsDgcaW4qBaMF7ra9aTpMCDAOmnremhnb+j20BYc+uEjh+hEIcRXgTJx3GZggFEQHmISFh0YHPpupqMbutZeGxCEuu6rhiEUADiFg5LE5CXkSN7ofeHTCRGr5iWOEneFOaZGUgJlGOZqSQtZRKKawUxoDExA0bs1EPupRqaVBTHaLBrEHuxcm+QAMhA-j+EFCp8XegmPthL7Du+bkTpJ6QZUU2W5flIWTIsUUgbFtEaZB25JVaul2mlBliEYnb0F+to-sArAsXWA0eeIw1QOwY0kUUU19fpc1DZ2ADy1zLV4u1rXBDZbeIEyZPtZ2ZEdqXwXN-mWcQ1m8HZ-EYY5YYiS5FUEVVHlSVAD2BZevBNWFEWtTFakdfFXXacx62zV4or1XlIMFb6b0Ob2n3OeV+GfkR6So89GBgy17XRfs7XrvRWlVgjx3sTAEyvXe5itFAq5OYO30E+5yMAyzTUtNING0wl3U6Uzg0LRM23kJdMmTSlM13cj82djATwTAAqplmVKygNQ3WrJ0LdrkwK5M+uG0TtrK1MJuwQAvoI4JYrE0KwrAp42RYqJMkS2K4lklJEtSJIhNQLxUjSiKxPSjKYiHbJZA8MB+7EECBynrIQHinJQDyt0NttxAmMQABCICZDl+CKttmW6wAsqzu2N83bdYJd5eVzXdf+Pg2qlRM3BoEpMNlnD5oZKLMh0ZL8PJZn-s5wy6J56HmSUIj6tOn3sQ12IQ+d637cUnATfnz39veIf1cgCfw8MKP4+TxLM+qH48+fxWUswVXtnXOzJU4FyyLvGWc1Mo2DQBeMYNkoDRgAO7+EujAuBKt6CCVYJEcKsRqxAIDhvIOLJt6QNLuxcyCAUBgBrk+CMPNMBoLvl4ahtCa4j2fGPCeBpF5f2oD-SQ0g-4MQZivLOxDk6gPzoXPeDYTB4FyGzf0CdkRxiSAGCAAA6S6iiIC5G1NWNEw4bAylIAGBANgjCQJdmCCEXsYTQAAFJWIwNtDAIDg6yLDrHCOHwjjR3DsSWkicvFkLTpkB4ri7AePCWAwu3IoEaxgBgdYSwABWbifqEwMhAewsA0mxBiZ48gv0q4PAAERREqZQeglSynjirpUqpNT2DaLokwZKjBtHcG0dY9pckvRdOoD0qI2iwApxgEYdp2jdGsMKekkprBSAVMeMEyOgTvj0EqjwyeUS4xIBsNKPM1YSlxPIFAAAZDcVZDwsCUGkd48h8j2J4GKMAKAWS7A5IFk6fJUBsofJKRQcprTan1MaXgZp4L2mdMYN03p-SZnaKGQgEZUAxkTKmSiuZ6DVjAGWVAO56y-HEi2fYOpuz36sAOa4Y585HhnLcRc65ty1kPKeRE8BO9XkGWCPYS8nzvkKn5n9DWALrg2EFYStxoKmngrqQ08pLSoDVMqXC58GKel9IGai7ywyEWjO0eMyZoDpmzPmdVW0UqZVEpJU8MlmzlxUt+ns2lDx6UnKZTBc5pS2W3A5Y8zeMiXnpEkR-CN8SfG8sEHY92HtITezhAACW4AGEI0bt4bICS6nNsA1FJxDc8yJGc00ZocFmyJRcS73wrkfWu9cuFGndVPCC-9GJz2EQvTqHbxHUBgOWzNJCt7Vr6g-Y+Q9m3yFbaI+m39xDdrnYlQhQ7K0jtDWO4msCLxNTwRFQhUaN0lp5RQ7w7C6EgGnZgWd-C+0Lt-nesR0EV5rvsFW09fV9GGIYMY0x5jLHWNsUAA)